# Can't iterate output as a list inside the loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, save

The below code works fine outside the loop but didn't produce iterating results inside the loop.

```
 elvalue <- function(x)
{
height= list(
zmean   = mean(x),
zmax    = max(x),
zsd     = sd(x),
zmin    = min(x)
)
return(height)
}
rawlist <- list.files(path = "./data/lidar/lidar_16/clipraw", pattern = ".las$",  full.names = T, recursive = FALSE)

for(i in 1:length(rawlist)){
readlas <- readLAS(rawlist[i])
lasdf <- data.frame(readlas@data)
cls2 <- subset(lasdf, lasdf$Classification==2)
ht2 <- elvalue(cls2$Z)
cls3 <- subset(lasdf, lasdf$Classification==3)
ht3 <- elvalue(cls3$Z)
cls4 <- subset(lasdf, lasdf$Classification==4)
ht4 <- elvalue(cls4$Z)
cls5 <- subset(lasdf, lasdf$Classification==5)
ht5 <- elvalue(cls5$Z)
allht <- list(ht2, ht3, ht4, ht5)
```

It gives the output only for first file which is as follows: The output is in the list format so how can I iterate for all files simultaneously and save it as a separate data frame.

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$zmean
[1] 434.1715

[[1]]$zmax
[1] 501.41

[[1]]$zsd
[1] 27.11985

[[1]]$zmin
[1] 388.27


 [[2]]
 [[2]]$zmean
 [1] 430.5257

 [[2]]$zmax
 [1] 501.58

 [[2]]$zsd
 [1] 26.41594

 [[2]]$zmin
 [1] 388.33


 [[3]]
 [[3]]$zmean
 [1] 428.083

 [[3]]$zmax


[1] 503.12

[[3]]$zsd
[1] 29.06311

[[3]]$zmin
[1] 388.66

[[4]]
[[4]]$zmean
[1] 454.2379

[[4]]$zmax
[1] 520.27

[[4]]$zsd
[1] 26.27641

[[4]]$zmin
[1] 390.61
```

### Now I want to iterate the results and save it in a data.frame for all of the 17 files stored in my folder.

Thanks and Regards,
Yogendra

Comment: Hi Yogendra and welcome to StackOverFlow!  It would be better if you present a reproducible example of your problem. Nevertheless, take a look both to `unlist` and `lapply` functions.

Comment: Is the output in your question the contents of the `allht` object? It seems from the code you posted that you are just overwriting that object every iteration of the loop. Also, if you want the output in a data frame you can probably skip storing the results in a list. It might be helpful to have an example of what you want the final data frame to look like.